# javascript Object property undefined, but it's there

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, undefined

i have a json-file looking like this:

```
 { 
   "results": {
    "name1": {
        "printouts": {
            "property1": [{
                    "someName": "someText",
                    "someName2": "someURL",
                    "someName3": integer,
                    "someName4": boolean
                }
            ],
            "property2": [
                "someText"
            ],
            "property3": [
                "someText"
            ],
            "property4": [
                "someText"
            ],
            "property5": [
                "someText"
            ],
            "property6": [
                "someText"
            ]
        },
        "someName": "someText",
        "someName2": "someURL",
        "someName3": integer,
        "someName4": boolean
    },
    "name2": {
        "printouts": {
            "property1": [{
                    "fulltext": "someText",
                    "fullurl": "someURL",
                    "namespace": integer,
                    "exists": boolean
                }
            ],
            "property2": [
                "someText"
            ],
            "property3": [
                "someText"
            ],
            "property4": [
                "someText"
            ],
            "property5": [
                "someText"
            ],
            "property6": [
                "someText"
            ]
        },
        "someName": "someText",
        "someName2": "someURL",
        "someName3": integer,
        "someName4": boolean
    },
 ......
}
```

What i want is to access `property6` of each object in `printouts`.
What i've done so far:

```
 for (i in results) {
        if (someOtherArray.length < 1) {
            someOtherArray.push(i.printouts.property6.toString());
        }
```

But this gets me Error: Cannot read property property6 of undefined. What am i doing wrong?

Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: it may be **i.name.printouts.property6.toString()**

Comment: results should be an array, instead of an object, because of the double name property.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `"` in there after `someText`  ► `"property5": [someText"],`

Comment: `i` will hold key name in string. You will have to use `results[i]` to get object

Comment: @NinaScholz results is not an array. it's an object with {}.

Comment: @dnks23, but you have twice `name` keys inside.

Comment: @NinaScholz Nicely spotted.

Comment: @NinaScholz i see what you are saying but i get this json-file from a server-response like this! `results` is with {} so not an array. any workaround for this?

Comment: @NinaScholz the `name` keys are not the same, it's just any string

Comment: @dnks23 If you are posting sample data to protect the real data you must provide valid data such as , no duplicate key names in the object and encapsulate strings correctly, etc.. Your Object as is is not valid.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have the wrong access to the property with

```
i.printouts.property6
```

it needs to be an object with a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with bracket notation for a variable.

```
data.results[i].printouts.property6
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then you could iterate over the keys and select the property you want.

```js
var data = { results: { name1: { printouts: { property1: [{ someName: "someText", someName2: "someURL", someName3: 33, someName4: false }], property2: ["someText"], property3: ["someText"], property4: ["someText"], property5: ["someText"], property6: ["someText"] }, someName: "someText", someName2: "someURL", someName3: 37, someName4: true }, name2: { printouts: { property1: [{ fulltext: "someText", fullurl: "someURL", namespace: 35, "exists": true }], property2: ["someText"], property3: ["someText"], property4: ["someText"], property5: ["someText"], property6: ["someText"] }, someName: "someText", someName2: "someURL", someName3: 34, someName4: false } } };

Object.keys(data.results).forEach(function (k) {
    console.log(data.results[k].printouts.property6);
});
```